# Oracle SQL: How to speed up or replace "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I got a SQL look likes below.  The problem is Table T2 is too big, which takes hours to download all data ( it takes 7 second to show the first 500 result though). Is there anybody know how to speed up "NOT IN" clause, or replace "NOT IN" by other exclusion methods? Thank you very much!

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE  NVL(T1.A,'1') NOT IN (SELECT B FROM T2)
```

Comment: Check out this link that describes how the `IN` is processed vs using `EXISTS` [Ask Tom: IN & EXISTS](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074)

Comment: Are the appropriate columns on `t1' and `t2` indexed? I would start there, then move on to rewriting the query (using a `LEFT JOIN` or `EXISTS` or something else) if the effect is minimal.

Comment: You can also write `<>ALL` -  but this is just another syntax, it will do exactly the same. :-)

Comment: How many rows are in `T1`? Do you have index on `T2(B)`? Does '1' exists in `T2`?

Answer (score 4):

You could rephrase your query using a join between the `T1` and `T2` tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON NVL(T1.A, '1') = T2.B
WHERE T2.B IS NULL
```

This might speed things up if you had indices on the join column, in particular an index on `T2`'s `B` column.

Answer (score 0):

If the table `T1` has very small number of records **and** if the table `T2`has an index on the column `B` your desired access plan is to perform *one index lookup in `T2` for each record in `T1`*.

The expected execution plan uses  **NESTED LOOP ANTIJOIN**.

If the requirements are fullfiled and the optimizer statistics are fresh this plan will be choosen by Oracle automatically - you need not to reformulate the query as recomended in other answer.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |     5 |   130 |   106   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                |        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI SNA|        |   100 |  2600 |   106   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | T1     |   100 |  1300 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN    | T2_IDX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | T2     |  4236 | 55068 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "T2" "T2" WHERE "B" IS NULL))
   4 - access("B"=NVL("T1"."A",1))
   5 - filter("B" IS NULL)
```

The problem with this execution plan is that it linerary scales with the *number of row in `T1`*, i.e. if the `T1`is large (M of rows)  the query will cease to perform. In this case the desired access is to make **one FULL SCAN** on each table.

The expected plan is **HASH ANTIJOIN**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   100 |  2600 |  5479   (1)| 00:01:38 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI NA |      |   100 |  2600 |  5479   (1)| 00:01:38 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |   100 |  1300 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2   | 84722 |  1075K|  5476   (1)| 00:01:38 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("B"=NVL("T1"."A",1))
```

Final note - you use `NVL(T1.A,'1')`  in the condition - does the value '1' exists in the table `T2`? If this is know and constant, you may simple include or exclude all NULL values from `T1` without lookuping the `T2`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the helps from everybody. 
A little bit more background:
1. Both T1 and T2 has index 
2. T2 has value '1', but that is not we want. The reason we used NVL("T1"."A",1) is because We want to keep null value records in A column in the final result.

So, I modified query as below and it is much faster and take only 10 minutes to run and download.

WITH T3 AS (SELECT DISTINCT B FROM T2)

SELECT T1.*

FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.A = T3.B

WHERE T3. B IS NULL AND T1.A IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT T1.*

WHERE T1.A IS NULL